# Random element of List<T> from LINQ SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, random

I'm using `C# 3.5` and am currently using `Linq` to get all users from a user table and put them in a list.

Now I would like to return a random user from that list. What's the best way to go about doing that?

Edit: Found it here:
[How to get a Random Object using Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173718/linq-how-to-get-a-random-object-using-linq)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Like this:

```
var rand = new Random();
var user = users[rand.Next(users.Count)];
```

Comment: Note: In real code `var rand = new Random();` should be initialized somewhere else so that it will only be seeded once.  If this code is called multiple times in quick succession, the new instances of `Random` may end up using the same seed and thus returning the same value when calling `Next`.

Comment: Indeed, this rand could be `static`

Comment: I belive users collection is zero base so it should be like: var user = users[rand.Next(users.Count-1)];

Comment: @Roman Count -1 isn't needed, `rand.Next` "Returns a non-negative random integer that is **less** than the specified maximum"

Answer (score 38):

Use [`ElementAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb299233.aspx):

```
var rand = new Random();
var user = users.ElementAt( rand.Next( users.Count() ) );
```

Answer (score 16):

Why not create a generic helper and/or extension?!

```
namespace My.Core.Extensions
{
    public static class EnumerableHelper<E>
    {
        private static Random r;

        static EnumerableHelper()
        {
            r = new Random();
        }

        public static T Random<T>(IEnumerable<T> input)
        {
            return input.ElementAt(r.Next(input.Count()));
        }

    }

    public static class EnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static T Random<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input)
        {
            return EnumerableHelper<T>.Random(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage would be:

```
        var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        var output = list.Random();
```

Answer (score 10):

for Entity Framework or Linq 2 Sql, can use this extension method

```
public static T RandomElement<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, Expression<Func<T,bool>> e)
{
   var r = new Random();
   q  = q.Where(e);
   return q.Skip(r.Next(q.Count())).FirstOrDefault();
}
// persons.RandomElement(p=>p.Age > 18) return a random person who +18 years old
// persons.RandomElement(p=>true) return random person, you can write an overloaded version with no expression parameter
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this?

```
var users = GetUsers();
var count = user.Count();
var rand = new System.Random();
var randomUser = users.Skip(rand.Next(count)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: If it's an `IList<T>`, you don't need LINQ.

Comment: Quite right, but the way the question was phrased there is a lot of room for ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

```
list.OrderBy(x=> Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10)
```

Comment: Not really what was asked - also this is highly inefficient.

Comment: OpenAI says this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The `Random` class can be used to generate pseudo-random numbers. Use it to generate a random number within the range of valid indices into your array or list.

```
Random rand = new Random();
var user = Users[rand.Next(Users.Count)];
```

If you want to see more examples, I created several random-oriented LINQ extensions and published it in the article [Extending LINQ with Random Operations](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/linq/extending-linq-with-random-operations).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly applicable in all cases but below is an alternative solution that I found handy since I was already using [Bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) in my project.

```
List<User> myUserList = _context.Users.ToList();

var _faker = new Faker("en");
User randomUser = _faker.Random.ListItem<User>(myUserList);
```