# How to efficiently retrieve a list of random elements from an IQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've seen the following:

[Random element of List<T> from LINQ SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615410/random-element-of-listt-from-linq-sql)

What I'm doing now - to get three random elements - is the following:

```
var user1 = users.ElementAt( rand.Next( users.Count() ) );
var user2 = users.Where(u => !u.Equals(user1)).ElementAt( rand.Next( users.Count() ) );
var user3 = users.Where(u => !u.Equals(user1) && !u.Equals(user2)).ElementAt( rand.Next( users.Count() ) );
```

But this is obviously unweildy and inefficient.  How can I do this elegantly and efficiently with one trip to the database?

EDIT: Based on below answer, I made the following extension method:

```
    public static IQueryable<T> SelectRandom<T>(this IQueryable<T> list, int count) {
        return list.OrderBy(_ => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(count);
    }    

    var result = users.SelectRandom(3);
```

BUT it seems like this would be inefficient for large datasets.  Another proposal is to take the `.Count()` of the IQueryable, select n random numbers that fall within that result, and then shoot a query to the db with the selected random indices... but the `Count()` might be expensive here.

Comment: @IanMercer I'm not asking how to orderBy random, I'm asking how to select n random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
users.OrderBy(_ => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(3)
```

This retrieves the first 3 elements from the users table, while sorting them by a value which is different each time.

Compared to AD.Net's answer.. well you'd require a list of userids generated randomly.. it doesn't suggest a way to do that

Comment: Interesting... Would you mind explaining how this works, and how it compares to the other answer?

Comment: @RobVious NewGuid() generates a new random GUID, so when youorder by it you will get a random ordering, and it'll be different everytime you execute that line.

Comment: Nice!  I updated my question with an extension method for this.

Comment: LOOKS COOL FOR 1 MILLION USERS TABLE. (we are executing some SQL here)
There is a word "efficiently" in question, and we are generating GUIDS  for each user and then sort all those strings, and take 3 from this beautiful list.

Comment: @ValentinKuzub - my db contains <10,000 rows, but I'm curious - how would you handle this for large datasets?

Comment: A `Guid` isn't random. At least there is no guarantee that it will be. `System.Random` is always preferable, but you'd need to bring the records back into memory for that.

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339192/linq-orderby-random this question handles all my concerns beautifully. Having random value in database is very important for "efficient" solution

Comment: From what I can see, the method proposed by Ian Mercer (above link) will still sort the whole table. The difference is the way it generates the sort key.. XORing a key in the database with a random seed is certainly quicker than generating a guid for each row, but it doesn't avoid the fact that the whole table will be sorted first

Comment: @Enigmativity `NewGuid()` is not predictable or sequential, so works well for this problem. I'm not sure why you say it's "not random". System.Random is entirely predictable if the same seed is used.

Comment: @slugster - being "not predictable" nor "sequential" does not mean it is random. `System.Random` is predictable AND it is random. What you want from a random number stream is high degree of entropy and a uniform distribution - both of which `Guid` doesn't have.

Comment: @enig Can you show that NewGuid() is predictable or not uniformly distributed? I suspect you can't, which makes it fine for this use. IOW it's random enough even if it doesn't fit some technical academic criteria (which System.Random doesn't fit either).

Comment: @slugster - Of course I can. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621563/how-random-is-system-guid-newguid-take-two. Also, Eric Lippert says "Now, this is assuming that the GUIDs are chosen by a perfectly uniform random process. They are not. GUIDs are in practice generated by a high-quality pseudo-random number generator, not by a crypto-strength random number generator." & "GUIDs are guaranteed to be unique but not guaranteed to be random. Do not use them as random numbers. " (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/05/07/guid-guide-part-three.aspx)

Comment: @Enigmativity That's an excellent reference, that explanation adds some value to the answer.