# How to randomize array items and then crop the array by required percent

Tags: c#

What is the best way to randomize items in an array and also remove random items to get to a required array length?

Let's say I have an array with 100 items.

First, I want to randomize it.

Then, I have three percent coefficients: 10%, 30%, 60%.

I want to remove items from the original array so the new array I get will be 60% of the original size (60 items), then 30%, then 10%.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to randomise the array would be to use a [Fisher-Yates-Durstenfeld shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm). You could either do this in-place (ie, shuffle the existing array) or create a new collection containing the items in random order.

Here's how I'd probably do it, [creating a new shuffled collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653204/55847) rather than mutating the original array, and then using [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) to get the required sub-sequences of the shuffled array. (And it would be easy enough to alter this code to [perform an in-place shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5589250/55847) instead, if you prefer.)

```
// uses Shuffle extension from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653204/55847
var temp = original.Shuffle().ToArray();
var sixty = temp.Take((int)(temp.Length * 0.6)).ToArray();
var thirty = temp.Skip(sixty.Length).Take((int)(temp.Length * 0.3)).ToArray();
var ten = temp.Skip(sixty.Length + thirty.Length).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all you can't remove items from an array. The size of an array is determined when it's created,  and can never change after that. If you want a smaller array, you have to create a new one.

You can shuffle the items using an extension like this:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions {

  public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Random rnd) {
    List<T> items = new List<T>(list);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++) {
      int pos = rnd.Next(i, items.Count);
      yield return items[pos];
      items[pos] = items[i];
    }
  }

}
```

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the coefficients, but I guess that you want to get the first 60% in one array, then another 30% in second array, then another 10% in a third array:

```
IEnumerable<int> shuffled = originalArray.Shuffle(new Random()).ToList();

int cnt60 = (int)Math.Round(originalArray.Length * 0.6);
int cnt30 = (int)Math.Round(originalArray.Length * 0.3);
int cnt10 = (int)Math.Round(originalArray.Length * 0.1);

int[] first60 = shuffled.Take(cnt60).ToArray();
int[] next30 = shuffled.Skip(cnt60).Take(cnt30).ToArray();
int[] next10 = shuffled.Skip(cnt60+cnt30).Take(cnt10).ToArray();
```