# remaining values from HashSet into secondary out

Tags: c#, hashset

We've been asked to create a program which takes 2 input (which I have parsed) for seats and passengers in a plane and randomly place passengers on seats in a plane in one output as well as placing the remaining seats in a secondary output.

I was wondering if there is a simple way to replace the remaining values in `HashSet`, into the `listBoxLedige`.

As it works now, the seats are being distributing but the values in the secondary output arent related the the first output.

```
if(passengers > seats)
{
    MessageBox.Show("For mange passagerer");
}
else
{
    HashSet<int> check = new HashSet<int>();
    for(int i = 0; i <= passengers - 1; i++)
    {
        int resultat = rnd.Next(1, seats + 1);
        while(check.Contains(resultat))
        {
            resultat = rnd.Next(1, seats + 1);
        }
        check.Add(resultat);
        int[] passagerer01 = new int[passengers];
        passagerer01[i] = i+1;
        listBoxFulde.Items.Add("Passager #" + passagerer01[i] + "på sæde #" + resultat);
    }
    HashSet<int> ledige01 = new HashSet<int>();
    for(int i = 0; i <= (seats - passengers - 1); i++)
    {
        int tilbage = rnd.Next(1, seats + 1);
        while(ledige01.Contains(tilbage))
        {
            ledige01.Add(tilbage);
        }
        listBoxLedige.Items.Add("Sæde #" + tilbage);
```

Comment: Couldn't you use [`HashSet.ExceptWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299875.aspx) which removes all elements from the set that are in the collection? So the remaining values are all items that you want to add to the listbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'd do (see [`Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) and [`ExceptWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299875.aspx)):

```
HashSet<int> ledige01 = new HashSet<int>(
    Enumerable.Range(1, seats));

ledige01.ExceptWith(taken);
```

**Note** in generating the seeds you can remove the trial and error by simply shuffling the seats and taking the first N:

```
var taken = HashSet<int>(Enumerable.Range(1,seats).Shuffle().Take(passengers));
```

For hints on how to do shuffle, see e.g. [Optimal LINQ query to get a random sub collection - Shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651619/optimal-linq-query-to-get-a-random-sub-collection-shuffle/1653204#1653204)

---

As an aside:

```
    int[] passagerer01 = new int[passengers];
    passagerer01[i] = i+1;
    listBoxFulde.Items.Add("Passager #" + passagerer01[i] + "på sæde #" + resultat);
```

looks to be something other than you need :) But I'm assuming it's unfinished and you're likely aware of that

A 'fully' edited take:

```
if(passengers > seats)
{
    MessageBox.Show("For mange passagerer");
}
else
{
    HashSet<int> taken = new HashSet<int>();
    for(int i = 0; i <= passengers - 1; i++)
    {
        int resultat;
        do {
            resultat = rnd.Next(1, seats + 1);
        } while(taken.Contains(resultat));

        taken.Add(resultat);

        listBoxFulde.Items.Add("Passager #" + (i+1) + "på sæde #" + resultat);
    }

    HashSet<int> ledige01 = new HashSet<int>(
        Enumerable.Range(1, seats));

    ledige01.ExceptWith(taken);

if(passengers > seats)
{
    MessageBox.Show("For mange passagerer");
}
else
{
    HashSet<int> taken = new HashSet<int>();
    for(int i = 0; i <= passengers - 1; i++)
    {
        int resultat;
        do {
            resultat = rnd.Next(1, seats + 1);
        } while(taken.Contains(resultat));

        taken.Add(resultat);

        listBoxFulde.Items.Add("Passager #" + (i+1) + "på sæde #" + resultat);
    }

    HashSet<int> ledige01 = new HashSet<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, seats));

    ledige01.ExceptWith(taken);

    foreach(var tilbage in ledige01)
        listBoxLedige.Items.Add("Sæde #" + tilbage);
```

Comment: Really appreciate the answer. I used the int array to produce the passenger numbers. As I mentioned I am a complete newbie. I did indeed consider ExceptWith but I havent been able to figure out how to use it to produce an output in the listBox.

Comment: Oh, lol. I thought that was trivial, I've expanded the bit under `// etc` now. Cheers (ps. I'm assuming `tilbage` means _available_ or _empty_ or something. We don't all speak Mandarin :))

Comment: Again, its 4 hours totally without any experience coding anything before so most of us are pretty clueless. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure I understand your problem, but have you taken a look at the `Except` LINQ extension method? Judging by your wording ("remaining values"), it might be the right method for you.

**Edit** Here's how it's done:

```
 IEnumerable<int> empty = allSeats.Except(check);
```

Note how `empty` is now a *deferred* enumerator (unless you do a `.ToArray()`, `.ToList()` or similar on it).

Comment: It's not. You should always prefer member functions over generic Extension Methods. In this case because it's way more efficient given that things are already in a HashSet. Then again, until a plane has several hundreds of thousands of seats, it shouldn't become a bottleneck for this exercise. The principle holds: teach people to **use the correct data structures /correctly/**

Comment: @sehe I agree, people should know how to use data structures correctly, I'm definitely with you on that point. Still, `Except` should work fine, too. For more detail, refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397728.aspx.

Comment: excellent link. I'll +1 as with the caveat discussed, it is informative.

Answer (score 0):

Not a hundred percent sure I understand your problem or solution, but are you aware that you declare and initialize `passagerer01` once for each passenger, then deterministically  (not randomly) assign seat `i+1` to passenger `i` and afterwards throw away that array?  If you wanted to keep the information, you'd have to declare the array outside the `for` loop.

Also, it doesn't really seem like you're doing anything meaningful in that second part of your code.  To determine the empty seats, it would make sense to go through numbers 1 to `passengers`, check if they are in the set `check` and, if not, add them to set `ledige01`.  Or, of course, to do something equivalent using a library method as suggested by sehe.

As a last note, in computer science you usually start counting from zero.  Thus, you would usually have seat numbers `0` to `seats-1` and choose seats randomly like so: `rnd.Next(0, seats)`.  And you would usually loop like this: `for(int i = 0; i < passengers; i++)` instead of `for(int i = 0; i <= passengers - 1; i++)`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and take note of those tips for future projects. Most of this has been learning by doing so thats why the code is rather sloppy.