# Using LINQ to shuffle a deck

Tags: c#, linq, list, playing-cards

I am  attempting to write a simple card game. In an effort to come up with a good shuffling algorithm I came across Jeff Atwood's [post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/shuffling.html) on Coding Horror.

However When I view the contents of the object after calling the Constructor they are not shuffled.

Here is my attempt to use Jeff's Solution:

```
class MainDeck : List<Card>
{
   public MainDeck()
    {
        this.Add(new Card(1, "Hearts"));
        this.Add(new Card(2, "Hearts"));
        this.Add(new Card(3, "Hearts"));
        ...

        this.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}
```

here is the code for Card:

```
class Card
    {
        string suit;
        int value;

        public Card(int value, string suit)
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.suit = suit;
        }

        bool isFaceCard()
        {
            if (value >= 11 || value == 1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return (value +", " + suit);
        }
    }
```

What should I change to make the shuffling work?

Comment: Please show the code for Card. Maybe it's just me, but without that I can't see how we can help.

Comment: You need to understand that `OrderBy` *returns* an ordered collection - it doesn't sort in-place. I'd also argue that Jeff is just shifting from one source of pseudo-randomness to another - using a modified Fisher-Yates shuffle with a decent source of randomness is neater than using OrderBy, IMO.

Comment: Code Added. However the question has nothing to do with the Card Class, it has to do with any kind of enumerable object

Comment: @JonSkeet How could I order the contents of my object by Guid then?

Comment: Using Guid for sorting may be a bad idea. See Eric Lippert's comment on [a different answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3169165/945456) that states "**Use guids to generate uniqueness, never randomness**".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

LINQ methods are not mutating existing collections. So this statement does nothing at all: `this.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid());`
Also, I'm pretty sure you can't assign to `this`, so you have to either don't inherit from `List<T>` (which is good), or do something like this:

```
var sorted = this.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
this.Clear();
this.AddRange(sorted);
```

Also look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262619/1418097), there is more correct shuffling algorithm.

Comment: Where did you get the `AddAll` function?

Comment: @jth41 this was a mistake (didn't remember the name of that method). Edited.

Comment: using your solution, `this` ends up with 0 elements after attempting `this.AddRange(sorted);`

Comment: @SargeBorsch your query does not work without `ToList()`, because it's not executed until `AddRange` is being called, so you're running the query on empty list (as `Clear` was already called). You always have to remember that LINQ queries are lazy and deferred.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek oops, you catched me! (I did know this) :)

Comment: Found an interesting comment by Eric Lippert on [a different answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3169165/945456) explaining why you shouldn't use Guid to sort: "it is legal for guids to be generated sequentially from an initial random element.... **Use guids to generate uniqueness, never randomness**" (edited for brevity, emphasis by me).

Comment: I only "used" it to keep the code obviously similar to the code in the question. *of course,* this is inadequate solution.

Answer (score 17):

Use this extension method

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Randomize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return source.OrderBy((item) => rnd.Next());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
 public void Shuffle()
 {
     Random r = new Random();
     this.Sort((x, y) => r.Next(-1, 1));
 }
```

Because of Linq's deffered execution following line doesn't get executed.

```
this.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid());
```

This just creates the query but never executed. Even if executed it won't change your collection.

Don't forget Linq is a way to query data, not mutate it.

Comment: You shouldn't use non-pure functions in Sort, because (by contract) `.Sort()` is free to evaluate your lambda multiple times. Instead you should use `.Select()` to add a random number into a anonymous struct, and then sort by that.